# Limit involving $\frac{0}{0} $ and $\sin 2x$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I'm currently working with the limits:

$$\frac{\sin(2x)}{e^x-1}$$

for $x\to 0$ and $x\to \infty$

how can this be solved? I tried to reformulate $\sin(2x)$ to $2\sin x\cos x$

---

Using L'Hõpital's rule, one can solve limits like this, where you end up with the indeterminate form $$\frac{0}{0}.$$

In this case, both

$\sin(2x)$ and $e^x-1$ are [differentiable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable) and both sublimits equals 0. Therefore the answer is:
$$\frac{D\sin(2x)}{D(e^x-1)}$$ = $$\frac{\cos(2x)*2}{e^x}$$

where $\cos(2x)$ is going towards 1 and $e^x$ is going towards $1$

what is left is $$\frac{1*2}{1}=2.$$

(*another precondition is that $${D(e^x-1)}$$ $\lim \rightarrow 0$ cannot be zero which its not:)*)

Comment: Nope, had not heard about it directly. I have a book that tries to explain something similar but in a really boring and complicated shortcut way. I read about it in wikipedia and try to learn. Thank you

Comment: Try the L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: I will try to learn this rule. The hint with the fundamental limits helped me to solve the task but It did not give me any sort of understanding or joy:P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT** Use the fundamental limits $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$ and for $x\to\infty$ observe that $\sin x$ is bounded.